# Perl catch runtime error

Tags: perl, runtime, try-catch

I am writing a perl script to open a textfile and perform some transformations on it. script is throwing an error saying "No such file or directory exists" whenever text file is unavailable.

I want to catch that error and create textfile then.

```
while (<>) {       #i am passing filename from the batch file
    #some task
}
# if the above while loop fails it throws no such file or directory exists error. I want to  catch it and do some other task.
```

Answer (score 1):

Those particular errors are warnings sent to STDERR by the "magic" behind `ARGV`. Why don't you just redirect STDERR?

```
perl script.pl foo bar 2>error.log
```

If that's not good enough, you'll have to start using `$SIG{__WARN__}` (yuck) or stop using `ARGV` (`<>` with no file handle defaults to using `ARGV`).

```
for my $argv (@ARGV ? @ARGV : '-') {
    open(my $argv_fh, $argv)
       or do {
             ... print message to log file ...
             next;
          };

    while (<$argv_fh>) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to catch the warning that the file doesn't exist, why not try passing the file path via [getopt](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) and test for file existence/readability before opening using [file test operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

edit: updated with example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

my %opts;
getopt('f', \%opts);

die "use -f to specify the file" unless defined $opts{f};

if(! -e $opts{f} ){
    print "file doesn't exist\n";
}
elsif(! -r $opts{f} ){
    print "file isn't readable\n";
}
elsif(! -f $opts{f} ){
    print "file is not a normal file\n";
}
else{
    open( my $fh, '<', $opts{f} ) or print "whatever error handling logic\n";
}
```

Comment: File tests won't get all the errors. Only `open` will be reliable, at which point there's no reason to use `<>`.

Comment: I think I misunderstand the question then, I read it as 'if file name passed to script doesn't exist then create the file and perform other logic, if file passed to script does exist do something else'.  Wouldn't file tests suit that?

Comment: I believe that just checks the 'r' flag, not readability. But even if it does, there are many other possible errors `open` can return.

Comment: indeed, I'm just suggesting that file tests are used to handle what they can, as my interpretation of the question was that  'if file name passed to script doesn't exist then create the file and perform other logic' given that that is a specific failure it can be tested for.  Dont think I"m being very clear in text, have updated my answer to show code of what I mean